# Intuition behind sub-Gaussian and sub-exponential random variables

Tags: probability, probability-theory, statistics, random-variables, concentration-of-measure

As I was reading about Gaussian random variable (RV) and Chernoff Bounds, I came across sub-Gaussian & sub-exponential RVs. After much analysis, I still couldn't figure what purpose sub-Gaussian & sub-exponential serve in the broader realm of statistics.

So my question is: How do sub-Gaussian & sub-exponential RVs relate to Gaussian RV in an intuitive sense? How should I decide when sub-Gaussian/sub-exponential RVs are suitable for a particular scenario?

An answer combining intuition and mathematics would be helpful.